# Deployment of Laravel 10 project on shared hosting - symlink problem

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

I know it's not the most ideal way to deploy a Laravel project, but this particular one is a small temporary project and I would like to deploy it via my reseller package.

Everything works perfect on development server and I deployed the way it did many times in the past:

- In the root directory of the webserver, I made a folder with the name of the project.
- I ftp'ed everything in that folder, except for the Laravel public folder
- I copied the files from the public folder to the public_html folder
- I did the necessary adjustments to the index.php file inside the public_html folder.
- in the appServiceProvider I added the following to the boot method:

```
    public function boot(): void
        {
             $this->app->bind('path.public',function(){
        return base_path('public_html');
        });
        }
```

I created the database and imported a database dump from my local machine.

Everything works perfectly, apart from the symlink that doesn't seem to work. I supposed it should work out of the box, since it did on the local machine, but that is not the case.

I tried to establish the link with the following route:

```
Route::get('/linkstorage', function () { $targetFolder = base_path().'/storage/app/public'; $linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage'; symlink($targetFolder, $linkFolder); });
```

Images that are uploaded using a form in the application are getting stored in the storage/app/public folder, but are not displayed on the site.

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks!

Comment: What is "the symlink" and how does it not work? If something isn't working it will be in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Hi many reseller package of hosting does not provider symlink since for the security purposes to all. You have to contact the hosting team and get support for the symlink.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Make sure you removed the already created symlink file in public folder and run the above command. If its not working contact the hosting team for support.